# Dealing with dates in a R data frame

Tags: r

I'm having trouble dealing with dates in my R code.

I have a data frame consisting of local temperatures and humidity measurements with the date (dd/mm/YY format) and a timestamp (hh:mm:ss, in 24h format).

The data frame looks like this:

```
        day     hour  hum temp
1 19/3/2020 13:39:34 53.0 31.8
2 19/3/2020 13:54:34 53.1 31.7
3 19/3/2020  14:9:33 53.5 30.9
4 19/3/2020 14:24:33 54.1 31.2
5 19/3/2020 14:39:33 53.8 31.3
6 19/3/2020 14:54:33 53.5 31.4
```

I want to plot daily temperature and humidity fluctuations, however when I use the following code:

```
df %>
filter(date == '19/03/2020' &
!is.na(temp)) %>%               # I have to filter NAs to remove failed measurements (empty cells)
ggplot(aes(day, temp, color = temp)) +
geom_line()
```

It generates an empty plot with just the axis names (y = temp and x = day)

The only way I'm able to get a plot is when I use

```
df %>%
ggplot(aes(day, temp, color = temp) +
geom_poin(alpha = 0.2) +
geom_jitter() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)
```

[Example plot: note the dates on the x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vGEZ.png)

However, the dates in the x-axis are sorted by the first digit of the date (see picture). This data frame consists of over 8000 measurements spanning from March to June (beginning in 19/03/2020) so the dates are plotted out of order, like this:

```
1 - 01/04/2020
2 - 01/05/2020
3 - 01/06/2020
4 - 02/04/2020
5 - ...
```

My final goal is to plot temp and hum with timestamps and facet by day so I can get different plots for different days. Something like this:

```
df %>%
filter(!is.na(temp)) %>%
ggplot(aes(hour, temp, color = temp) +
geom_line() +
facet_grid(.~day)
```

So, my questions are:

1. How do I deal with dates in ggplot so they are properly plotted?
2. When I run `str()` it returns that `df$day` and `df$hour` are 'character' classes. Shouldn't they be considered something else? Maybe that is why my code doesn't work...

Comment: You will need to convert the "day" variable into dates to address the issue of axis order.  See the function `as.Date()`.  If you were working with a variable with date and times simultaneously you could work with something like `as.POSIXct()`.  You could still do this by pasting the `day` and `hour` together.  If you want to have a separate `hour` column that should be considered a time then see, e.g., packages **chron** or **lubridate**.

Comment: Your `day` varible is not a `Date` class variable. You can convert it this way: `df$day <- as.Date(df$day, "%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I was able to solve the problem with Eyayaw's comment and Limey's answer. I'm still having issues with the filter and using the timestamps but I'll take a look at the chron and lubridate packages before posting again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if your dates are character, so `'19/3/2020'` is not equal to `'19/03/2020'` so your filter returns an empty data frame.  Convert them to dates with `as.Date()`.  For more sophisticated parsing, look at the `lubridate` package.